# How qlpreviewcontroller works?

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller

I know how to use qlpreviewcontroller, but i am curious to learn what actually happened behind the scene of the controller. I am looking for a way to implement my own custom preview controller that allows me to do paginated swipe, horizontal layout, programmatically scroll to page, etc. the issue really is being able to crack open the files and extract them as an image. I know that there are services that allow you to do so, but i prefer a client side solution if possible
Anyone have any suggestion / insight?